# Как избежать сортировки объекта JSON по ключам?

Tags: javascript, json

На бекенде формирую json:

```
$conditions = json_encode(array(
    '3' => array('three'),
    '2' => array('two'),
    '1' => array('one'),
));
```

Сохраняю в атрибуте элемента страницы:

```
<div id="data" data-value="{"3":["three"],"2":["two"],"1":["one"]}">
```

Порядок следования элементов массива сохраняется. Но когда читаю этот json в javascript, получаю объект, сортированный по ключам. Можно ли этого как-либо избежать или единственный вариант - изменить ключи исходного массива в нужном мне порядке?

```
<script>
    console.log(data.dataset.value);
    // Object { 1: Array[1], 2: Array[1], 3: Array[1] }
</script>
```

Comment: Да, либо изменить ключи, что может быть так же не верно, т.к. с точки зрения JS вы формируете объект, а не массив. Либо добавить отдельный массив (они в json в квадратных скобках) с порядком ключей `['3','2','1']`

Comment: @Mike а кстати добавить второй массив это мысль. по крайней мере не придется перебирать весь исходный, `array_keys()` и всё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порядок следования элементов ассоциативного массива (словаря) не определён в JSON. Выдержка из [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
>      pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
>      boolean, null, object, or array.

По этой причине порядок Вам необходимо хранить самостоятельно.

1. Можно сохранить параллельно массив ключей в определённом порядке и использовать его для сортировки.
2. Также можно добавить в словарь ключ "вес" с численным значением и сортировать по нему.

Comment: Выдержка из того же RFC:  An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.
Достаточно отсортировать массив на сервере и удалить ключи при помощи array_values, тогда получим действительно массив, а не объект.